# getting started with the latest version of hadoop and ec2

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am following [Hadoop in Action](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/hadoop/9781935182191) to get started with hadoop with ec2. I'm running on ubuntu and have downloaded and installed the latest version of Hadoop. I am hitting a road block at this command:

```
hadoop-ec2 launch-cluster mycluster 2
```

---

> The book says "The Hadoop EC2 tools are in the directory
>   src/contrib/ec2/bin under your Hadoop installation. Recall that our
>   ec2-init.sh script has already added that directory to your system
>   PATH. Within that directory is hadoop-ec2, which is a meta-command for
>   executing other commands. To launch a Hadoop Cluster on ec2 use:
>
> **hadoop-ec2 launch-cluster < cluster-name> < number-of-slaves>**"

---

The response I get is: `hadoop-ec2: command not found`

I noticed that the variable `$HADOOP_HOME` is not set.

It looks like this book is out-dated.

1. can someone direct me to a tutorial that was created in the last couple of months on how to set up hadoop with ec2?
2. After some quick googling, it seems that `HADOOP_HOME` is deprecated. Is this true?
3. I am able to without problems execute `ec2-describe-images`. and get all the available images that I can use. Why doesn't `hadoop-ec2` command work?

Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the dedicated page [Running Hadoop on Amazon EC2](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonEC2) (which doesn't facilitate `HADOOP_HOME` indeed) turns out to be fairly out of date in itself and doesn't seem to apply to the most recent stable version anymore (1.0.4 at the time of this writing). I'm not aware of an updated 'native' tutorial, but apparently users are quite happy with an approach via [Apache Whirr](http://whirr.apache.org/) (which incidentally *started out in 2007 as some bash scripts in [Apache Hadoop](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-884) for running Hadoop clusters on EC2*).

Accordingly there is a [Getting Started with Whirr™](http://whirr.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/quick-start-guide.html) available, in addition there are also related 3rd party tutorials, e.g.:

- [Deploying Hadoop on EC2 with Whirr](http://chimpler.wordpress.com/2013/01/20/deploying-hadoop-on-ec2-with-whirr/)
- [How-to: Set Up an Apache Hadoop/Apache HBase Cluster on EC2 in (About) an Hour](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/10/set-up-a-hadoophbase-cluster-on-ec2-in-about-an-hour/)

I hope you'll be able to merge the information in the book about using [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) with these about running a Hadoop cluster via Apache Whirr - good luck!

Comment: thanks so much for your kind info!! could you please tell me for the latest version of hadoop (which i have installed) where would be the hadoop home directory?

Comment: i did this sudo find / -wholename '*hadoop/bin*'   and got no results!